# Find and load only nth div in Jquery using load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to load the content in specific div using the below load(). All the DIVs are having the same class. Suppose I wanted to replace 3rd div, how can I load the content? Can someone could assist me here? Please let me know if it is not clear.

E.g. `$(".classxyz").load(URL + " .testcontent");`

HTML Stricture:
Test1

```
<div class="classxyz">Test2</div>

<div class="classxyz">Test3</div>

<div class="classxyz">Test4</div>
```

Comment: `".classxyz:nth-child(3)";`

Comment: Hi Mohamed - Thanks for your reply. I am getting an error and not able to replace the content.    $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
$(".testcontent:nth-child(idx)").load(obj.url + " .container");
});

Comment: @vs2189 you must use `idx` properly. It cannot be in the String. `$(".testcontent:nth-child(" + idx + ")")`

Comment: Great thanks for your inputs, I am not getting the error but If i am replacing/loading both the divs (in my case, the loop will execute 2 times or more), the content in the first loop is getting updated for second div as well. Can you tell me how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Here is my code. can you advise?          $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    idx=idx+1;
     $(".testcontent:nth-child(" + idx + ")").load(obj.url + " .container");
});